# ошибка с C++ error expected primary-expression before ') ' token

Tags: c++, char

Пишу калькулятор, и ошибка

> error expected primary-expression before ') ' token

еще ошибка

> error expected primary-expression before '/' token

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a, b, y;
    cout << "y ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "a ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b ";
    cin >> b;
    if (y == +) {
        int c = a + b;
    } else if (y == -) {
        int c = a - b;
    } else if (y == *)  {
        int c = a * b;
    } else if (y == /) {
        int c = a / b;
    } else {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
    cout << c
    
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А как это вы сравниваете целое число с арифметическим оператором?... Если с символом - так он должен быть в кавычках, типа

```
if (y == '+') ...
```

Comment: спасибо работает